# Pairwise independent random variable implies conditional independence?

Tags: probability

If we have three pairwise-independent random variables X, Y and Z such as

X is independent of Y, X is independent of Z and Y is independent of Z.

Does it imply that X and Y are conditionally independent given Z?

Could you prove it or give a counter-example if false?

Answer (score 2):

Counter-example: Let $X, Y$ be iid [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) distributed, with $p=1/2$. And let $Z= X \oplus Y$ (XOR, or sum modulo-2).