# $X,Y$ independent from sigma algebra $\Sigma$ then also $X+Y$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

Let $X,Y$ be independent from a sigma algebra $\Sigma$. Does this mean that $X+Y$ is independent from $\Sigma$?

I just don't know how to show it, but maybe a yes/no answer and a good hint could help me already

If you have any questions about this, please let me know.

Comment: You can find a counter-example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457384/pairwise-independent-random-variable-implies-conditional-independence/1457424#1457424

Comment: There is no counterexample. The statement in the OP's question is true. The sigma-algebra generated by $X+Y$ is contained in the sigma-algebra generated by the pair $(X,Y)$.